# How to change text when I am reusing components in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project, In this project I have App.js that is Parent to Child.js. I have written some text in Child.js and I apply some styles to written text. and I reuse two times Child.js component in App.js.

Now same text will repeat two times in App.js, but I have to change the text for the second component. Without creating extra component

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react;
import './App.css';
import './Child/Child';

function App() {
return(
<div className='App'>
<Child/>
<Child/>

</div>

export default App
```

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';


function Child() {
    return (
        <div className='h4content'>
            <h4>Create An Account</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

This is Child.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:576px) {
    .h4content {
        text-align: center;
    }

}


.h4content h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.h4content {
    margin-top: 4% !important;
}
```

If you have any doubt please put a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the text as **`prop`** to the child:

```
import React from 'react;
import './App.css';
import './Child/Child';

function App() {
return(
<div className='App'>
<Child text={'Text for child #1'}/>
<Child text={'Text for child #2'}/>

</div>

export default App
```

and then access them in child:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';


function Child(props) {
    return (
        <div className='h4content'>
            <h4>{props.text}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```